# Trying to find missing declarations / statements in JS

Tags: javascript

Driving myself totally crazy trying to see how I messed up the declarations in this little chunk of code I am working on. Been tinkering for an hour and cant figure it out.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
                .then((idTokenResult) => {
                    console.log(idTokenResult)
                    // Confirm the user is paid
                    if (!!idTokenResult.claims.member) {
                        // Show paid UI
                        console.log("Membership Already Started")
                    } else {
                        // Show regular user UI.
                        let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                  const subCollRef = db.collection("stripe_customers").doc(user.uid).collection("charges");
                  const query = subCollRef.orderBy('created', 'desc').limit(1);
                        var d = new Date();
                        var year = d.getFullYear();
                        var month = d.getMonth();
                        var day = d.getDate();
                        var c = new Date(year + 1, month, day);
                        console.log(c);
                        query.get()
                        .then(snapshot => {
                          if (snapshot.size > 0 && snapshot.docs[0].data().status === "succeeded") {
                            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                            console.log(user.uid)
                            xhttp.open(
                                "POST",
                                "https://us-central1-*****y.cloudfunctions.net/addMemberRole",
                                true
                            );
                            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                            xhttp.send(
                                JSON.stringify({
                                    uID: user.uid
                                }),
                                console.log(xhttp.responseText)
                            );
                            console.log("should still be working HOPEFULLY HERE YOU ARE")
                            user.getIdToken(true)
                            setMembershipDate({
                                mDateS: d.getTime(),
                                mDateE: c.getTime()



                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                          console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                        })
                        })
                    }

                })
            }

        })
    })
```

The error states Declaration or statement expected. line 74 here is a snippet of line 74 from the code above

```
})
                        .catch(err => {
                          console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                        })
                        }) <---- line 74
```

Comment: Just add `}); }` after `c.getTime()`, and remove that line 74. `});` closes the call to `setMembershipDate`, and `}` closes the `if` statement

Comment: Lmao how did I miss that ugh. I swear a fresh pair of eyes is all it takes sometimes lol

Comment: That kind of problem would not happen if you used an auto-formatter while you code. Look up Prettier, and ESlint, they have plugins for many code editors, it will make your life easier ;)

Comment: +1 to fixing the indentation, would have helped you see it straight away because the brackets didn't line up

Comment: Prettier setup, you guys are the best =D